# Flash AS3 dynamically added children . Problem with naming them and calling each separated

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, addchild

I need to access each children after i dynamically added them to the stage , but i`m having problems figuring out how .

On click it adds the image to the stage , and I need to make them glow one at a time , with a for() , but I cant figure out how to name them each with its own name ( name + i ) to access them later on .

Thank you in advance

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clicky);
var i = 1; 
function clicky(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    i++;
    var fl_MyInstance:LibrarySymbol = new LibrarySymbol();
    addChild(fl_MyInstance);


    var myStageX:Number = Math.round(event.stageX);
    var myStageY:Number = Math.round(event.stageY);

    fl_MyInstance.x = myStageX;
    fl_MyInstance.y = myStageY;

        if(myStageX<150){
            fl_MyInstance.scaleX = fl_MyInstance.scaleY = 1-(myStageX/300);
        }else{
            fl_MyInstance.scaleX = fl_MyInstance.scaleY = 0.5;
            }
}
```

EDIT:
Thank you for your answers . I will try to do it with an array , considering that i want to make them removable later .
The point of the project is to create stars across the stage where you click and have a dot move from one star to another making them glow when it hits them .

Answer (score 3):

If you need to access them later by name you could do it by naming the symbols:

```
...
var fl_MyInstance:LibrarySymbol = new LibrarySymbol();
fl_MyInstance.name = "symbol_" + i;
addChild(fl_MyInstance);
...
```

I would add them to an Array or Vector instead. That way makes it easy to access them later on. It is also good when disposing them.

```
...
var fl_MyInstance:LibrarySymbol = new LibrarySymbol();
_symbolList.push(fl_MyInstance)
addChild(fl_MyInstance);
...
```

Comment: +1.  The way I do it.  Mentioning the use if Vectors got you the up vote.

Answer (score 1):

You can access them in an array using getChildren.  Something like this should work for you:

```
var children:ArrayCollection = this.getChildren();

foreach(var child:LibrarySymbol in children)
{
...do whatever
}
```

If you want to access them individually you can use getChild or getChildAt or something similar.  Using naming conventions with dynamic data is probably the hardest way to go through it.

Check here for more info: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=05_Display_Programming_08.html